# RabbitMQ crashing during restart

Tags: rabbitmq

When I try to start my rabbitmq server, I get following error in log/*-sasl.log

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 10-Apr-2013::23:24:32 ===
crasher:
initial call: application_master:init/4
pid: <0.69.0>
registered_name: []
exception exit: {bad_return,
                    {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
                     {'EXIT',
                         {undef,
                             [{os_mon_mib,module_info,[attributes],[]},
                              {rabbit_misc,module_attributes,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},
                                   {line,760}]},
                              {rabbit_misc,
                                  '-all_module_attributes/1-fun-0-',3,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit_misc.erl"},
                                   {line,779}]},
                              {lists,foldl,3,
                                  [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1197}]},
                              {rabbit,boot_steps,0,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,441}]},
                              {rabbit,start,2,
                                  [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,356}]},
                              {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                  [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                   {line,274}]}]}}}}
  in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 138)
ancestors: [<0.68.0>]
messages: [{'EXIT',<0.70.0>,normal}]
links: [<0.68.0>,<0.7.0>]
dictionary: []
trap_exit: true
status: running
heap_size: 2584
stack_size: 24
reductions: 227
neighbours:
```

startup_log has -

```
{error_logger,{{2013,4,11},{2,48,36}},std_error,"File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7/ebin. Function: read_file_info. Process: code_server."}

=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Apr-2013::02:48:36 ===
File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7/ebin. Function: read_file_info. Process: code_server.
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Apr-2013::02:48:36 ===
File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7. Function: list_dir. Process: application_controller.

=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Apr-2013::02:48:36 ===
File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7. Function: list_dir. Process: application_controller.
Skipping /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.2.8/ebin/os_mon_mib.beam (unreadable)

=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Apr-2013::02:48:36 ===
File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7. Function: list_dir. Process: systools_make.

=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Apr-2013::02:48:36 ===
File operation error: eacces. Target: /usr/lib64/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.7. Function: list_dir. Process: systools_make.
```

startup_err has -

```
Erlang has closed

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{os_mon_mib,module_info,[attributes],[]},{rabbit_misc,module
```

Any help to understand the cause of the error would be great. Thanks.